# Layout align checkbox and date textview right in table layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="4dip" android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp" >
            <TextView android:id="@+id/text_sender" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:focusable="false"
                android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="20dp" android:layout_weight=".75" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/text_date" android:text="date"
                android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_gravity="right"  android:layout_weight=".25" android:focusable="false"
                android:layout_height="20dp" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="35dp" android:gravity="top">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/text_msg" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:layout_height="35dp" android:focusable="false" />

            <CheckBox android:layout_width="0dp" android:id="@+id/ck_msg" android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:checked="false" android:layout_height="35dp" android:focusable="false"
                android:layout_gravity="right"  />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

i want to aligh both of them to extream right

Comment: It is better to provide any screenshot how u want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use RelativeLayout for this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="4dip" android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:text="TextSender"
        android:id="@+id/text_sender"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:text="TextDate"
        android:id="@+id/text_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_sender"
        android:text=""
         />
    <TextView android:text="TextView"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_sender" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it works for design part but my weight attributes are not set as they are in my tablelayout

Answer (score 1):

this should work..

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="4dip" android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
         <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity = "right">
                    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="20dp" 
    android:layout_gravity = "right">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/text_sender" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:focusable="false"
                            android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="20dp" android:layout_weight=".75" />
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/text_date" android:text="date"
                            android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_gravity="right"  android:layout_weight=".25" android:focusable="false"
                            android:layout_height="20dp" />
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="35dp" android:layout_gravity = "right">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/text_msg" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight=".75"
                            android:layout_height="35dp" android:focusable="false" />

                        <CheckBox android:layout_width="0dp" android:id="@+id/ck_msg" android:layout_weight=".25"
                            android:checked="false" android:layout_height="35dp" android:focusable="false"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"  />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Dennis.. whats happening then... no change at all?